# On what trigger can I get an id_token silently via msalObj.acquireTokenSilent() method of MSAL?

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

What are the various ways of setting the trigger for `msalObj.acquireTokenSilent()` so that it gets called when the `id_token` stored in the local storage expires?
I had tried calling the function by calling it via `setTimeout()` but as the page refreshes setTimeout is lost.
Is there a more efficient way of implementing the above logic?

Answer (score 0):

We always start with `acquireTokenSilent` to obtain a token in the signed in user from cache. We will call `acquireTokenPopup` upon acquireTokenSilent  failure(token expires).

```
myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {
         callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint, tokenResponse.accessToken, graphAPICallback);
    }).catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
         // Upon acquireTokenSilent failure (due to consent or interaction or login required ONLY)
         // Call acquireTokenPopup(popup window)
         if (requiresInteraction(error.errorCode)) {
             myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {
                 callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint, tokenResponse.accessToken, graphAPICallback);
             }).catch(function (error) {
                 console.log(error);
             });
         }
    });
```

Comment: I have this in place, I wanted to call it periodically, once every hour when the token expires
So that I have a valid token in my cache.
I'm using Azure AD as an authentication gateway for my app, I want to keep a valid ID token in my cache.

Comment: For now, I've implemented polling using setInterval(), is there a better way?

Comment: @KaranTikku I don't think this is needed, it is reasonable that login required if the user didn't access the website for a long time.

Comment: @KaranTikku This is a security mechanism.

Comment: that makes sense, but how can I add a trigger such that the user is asked to login once the ID token expires? FYI I'm not using MSGraph API in my app.

Comment: @KaranTikku You can think of `acquireTokenSilent` method as a trigger, if you can not get the token by using this method, just redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: when will I call `acquireTokenSilent`? Is there any event or anything which gets triggered when the toke expires?
I have a poller right now which calls  `acquireTokenSilent` every 10 minutes to check if I have a valid token

Comment: @KaranTikku What is your application used for? Any sample did you refer to? https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-core